# Elastic Search Query the number of new vs returning users

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a time range, I want to know how many users are new users and how many users are returning users.

My Elastic search index mapping contain field user_id, event_time and etc.

e.g. Given a record (user_id: jack, event_time: 2019-10-31 00:00:00:000). If the user_id does not exist in the past 2 weeks (from 2019-10-17 00:00:00:000 to 2019-10-31 00:00:00:000), then we consider the record with user_id 'jack' is a new user. Otherwise it's considered as a returning user.

I was wondering that if Elastic search support such kind of query which can tell me the number of new users and returning users?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a range aggregation for that.

```js
{
  "aggs": {
    "activity": {
      "range": {
        "field": "event_time",
        "ranges": [
          { "to": "now-2w/d" },
          { "from": "now-2w/d" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should go through your whole index and create two buckets based on event time. One for anything that's older than two weeks, another one for everything that's newer than two weeks.